# What is the best caching framework available for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I am looking at various frameworks for implementing caching in ASP.NET.

High Performant distributed cache that I can setup for my asp.net solution where I can throw in all my meta data.

Comment: Perhaps fill in some more details, like what sort of caching / use-cases, as well as any existing solutions looked at and why they would (or would not) be suitable.

Comment: I think it is subjective, but not argumentative, and i think the best answer to this question will be the one with the most upvotes. voting to reopen

Comment: Thanks Matt. I am not sure why this question is closed. I am looking for any new caching solutions for ASP.NET. High Performant distributed cache that I can setup for my asp.net solution where I can throw in all my meta data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that the [built in cache capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are probably the simplest and easiest to use.